# Cannot log in to wifi

Tags: wireless, internet, dns, intel-wireless, 17.04

I just upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04.
At my school, I have one of those wifi networks where there is a password, but then every few days you are redirected to a sign-in page.
WiFi works fine generally, but I cannot get to that sign in page, and consequently, cannot log in.
The error I get on chrome is:

"mydomain's server DNS address could not be found."

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

I have tried other browsers, to no avail.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? I've found Chrome doesn't like to obey the dns servers you have set up on your system and instead prefers to follow its own rules. I've a dns server at home and Firefox works beautifully accessing my services by their host name but chrome works half the time and not the other half. 
The sign in page you're being directed to is probably locally hosted with a dns entry and maybe chrome is ignoring it and trying to search its own servers and coming back with a blank

Comment: I've tried Firefox, it gave me a similar error.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the wifi network from your known networks list and reconnecting?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well.

Comment: It look like a DNS problem but I'm assuming no one else is having issues connecting to the page?  You could try `nslookup path.to.signin.page` from a terminal to make sure your system's dns entries are correct.

Comment: Server can't find domainname: NXDOMAIN

Comment: I also get "non-authoritative answer:"

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your DNS. Does the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf ` and `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` look ok? Do you know what your dns should be or at least what subnet your school is using?

Comment: I found the ip of dns.school.edu, and the output of grep gives the same value. resolv.conf just shows "nameserver 127.0.0.53"

Comment: It looks like there could be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1647031  which is affecting you more because you **need** to use the assigned dns from your school. As a workaround you could try adding the ip address of your school's dns to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` and running `sudo resolvconf -u` the format of the contents of `tail` should be `nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: The other option would be to get the ip address of the sign in page and go to it directly

Comment: @Will adding to the tail file worked. Thank you so so much.

Comment: Ok I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there could be a bug bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1647031 which is affecting you more because you need to use the assigned dns from your school.

As a workaround you could try adding the ip address of your school's dns to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` and running `sudo resolvconf -u` the format of the contents of tail should be

`nameserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`